# NODE_PATH is being ignored or not working

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run my node app on a new server and am having some issues with the NODE_PATH environment variable. The app works fine on my local machine (OSX Lion) but not on the server (Redhat linux). When starting my app with `node app.js` from within my project directory `/development/nodeproject`, I get the following error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mod/core/models/Category'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at /development/nodeproject/app.js:57:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/development/nodeproject/app.js:258:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
```

`mod/core/models/Category` is the first require() in my app.js and looks like this: `var Category = require('mod/core/models/Category')`. So apparently node is not looking for modules in my project directory.

I'm not sure why though, because I made the following changes (that are working just fine on my local machine).

- added `export NODE_PATH=/development/nodeproject` to my ~/.bash_profile
- ran `source ~/.bash_profile`
- if I run `env` I see `NODE_PATH=/development/nodeproject` listed there
- in my app.js if I console log `process.env.NODE_PATH` I get `/development/framework` (should this output an array instead of a string?)

Other information that might be relevant:

- I'm on node v0.6.7
- I'm doing all of this as root (sudo su -)

At this point I'm not sure what else I can do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

NODE_PATH used for modules, not for solutions files.
Try 
    **module.paths.push("/development/nodeproject", "one/more/path");** 
before any require() call. And you really should use a relative require like **require('./mod/core/models/Category')** for files in your nodeproject directory

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for was removed. Use the `node_modules` directory or a relative require like `require('./mod/core/models/Category')`.

This answer has more info: [NODE_PATH error with node.js while attempting to setup jsctags for vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384840/node-path-error-with-node-js-while-attempting-to-setup-jsctags-for-vim)

Comment: I know `require.paths` has been removed. But both the NODE_PATH and the node_modules approach should still work as far as I know. The error in the answer you linked says so much and it's working with NODE_PATH and node v0.6.7 on my local machine.

The require.paths error (which I don't get but for reference):
    `Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, **or the NODE_PATH environment variable** instead.`